# Как определить геолокацию пользователя и вывод данных Nuxt.js + Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

Подскажите, есть фронтенд на Nuxtjs и бэкенд на Laravel

Вроде пришел к использованию google maps api(но не уверен)

Как перед загрузкой сайта определить город пользователя

Нужно будет вывести в шапке название города и перед загрузкой записать например данные геолокации в localStorage(или кэш) и вывести данные на сайте(успеть отправить на api Laravel) по этому городу